# hashCode() without equals()?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I know that implementing/overriding `equals()` without also overriding `hashCode()` violates the equals/hashCode contract.

But what if a class implements only `hashCode()` and not `equals()`?

Answer (score 3):

If a class has only `hashCode()` then it's not a problem: Objects that are `equal()` will have the same `hashCode()`.

This is because `equals()` will fall back to `Object`'s implementation, which is *identity*, which will of course give the same `hashCode()`

Answer (score 0):

If the object is the same, it must have the same hashCode.
If the object is different, it doesn't have to have a different hashCode.

so when hashCode is the same, it's not necessarily the same object.
But when hashCode is different, it must not be the same object.